# Como saber quando o ficheiro foi carregado 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, io

Tenho uma funcionalidade de faz o seguinte:

1. Carrega um vídeo, do PC do utilizador usando C#
2. Coloca o link do vídeo numa *src* de um  em HTML5 usando JQuery

O problema:

Ele coloca o link e mostra o player, mas como o vídeo ainda não fez upload a 100% não aparece nada no player. Passado alguns segundos, se carregar no play, começa sem problemas.

Guardo o vídeo assim:

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses, 
                              string pre_hash = "")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = context.Request.Files[i];

            var fullPath = StorageRoot + pre_hash + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);


            file.SaveAs(fullPath); // <---- GUARDO AQUI <---------------

            string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(pre_hash + fullName, file.ContentLength, 
                                          fullPath));
        }
    }
```

Como posso saber quando o ficheiro foi carregado (esta função guarda *N* ficheiros diferentes, no contexto desse problema vem sempre só um item para o loop)?

Comment: Olá @ihavenokia, você poderia adicionar o código completo?

Comment: eu só quero saber quando esse código, que eu postei, carrega completamente um ficheiro. Tipo um evento ou assim que possa usar no javascript

Comment: Por isso que pedi o seu código. Como você está fazendo o upload? Está enviado para o servidor por Ajax? Utilizando um POST? Sem mais informações não é possível lhe ajudar

Comment: de momento não tenho acesso ao código, mas faço upload usando um método C# que guarda o ficheiro no _filePath_ e guarda o caminho na base de dados. eu busco esse link em jQuery usando Ajax. o problema é que o link nos instantes iniciais aponta para um ficheiro incompleto(?)

Comment: nesse caso, voce deveria gravar na base, apenas quando seu ficheiro estivesse com o upload completo. até porque, se houver interrupção no meio do upload, você estará com algo gravado na base que nao existe no seu fileSystem, quebrando sua aplicação

Comment: a dúvida continua igual haha como posso saber se o processo de upload foi completado.

Comment: já adicionei mais código